# Is there any way to exit a named loop (or otherwise) from an class further up in the hierarchy?

Tags: java, loops, hierarchy

I have this layout of abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractMapper{

    protected abstract void doMap();

    protected String mapCode(final String code){

        if(code.length > 5){
            //continue mainLoop from mapper
        }
        return code;
    }
}
```

and this implementation of a mapper (one of many):

```
public class Mapper1{

    @Override
    public void doMap(){

        mainLoop: for(LoopVar var: LoopVars){

            String code = var.getCode();
            code = mapCode(code);
            //finish mapping
    }
}
```

I have mainLoop in ever implemented mapper, and in a lot of the mappers I call mapCode. However I'd like to continue the mainLoop every time my code length isn't what I want.

I know I can simply add in an additional check in every implemented mapper but there are a lot of mappers, ideally I'd like to do it all cleanly in the method of the abstract class (and I'd rather not have to name my loop either but mapCode is usually sitting inside a nested loop).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a `shouldContinueMainLoop(code)` in your abstract mapper ? This way it would be implemented in all available mappers, and be available as well in `Mapper1 call`. You would only have to change your mainLoop to

```
    mainLoop: for(LoopVar var: LoopVars){

        String code = var.getCode();
        if(shouldContinueMainLoop(code)) 
             continue;
        code = mapCode(code);
        //finish mapping
}
```